# VueJS: what does an html attribute prefixed with a colon signify?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Example:

```
<vue-select 
  class="vue-select1" 
  name="select1"
  :options="options1" 
  :model.sync="result1"
></vue-select>
```

What is the meaning the colon in front of `:options` and `:model.sync` here? I've searched all over the internet and can't find an answer anywhere.

Example seen here: https://github.com/Haixing-Hu/vue-select

Comment: This allows you to use variables, computeds etc (from your component of course) as attribute value instead of static values.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In a Vue template, a colon `:` prefixing an html attribute is [shorthand for `v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand).

[Here's the full documentation for `v-bind`.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

Comment: I'm not familiar with any other front-end frameworks that use this syntax. React and Angular definitely don't.

Comment: The React equivalent is to replace quotes around the attribute value with curly braces, in Vue you would have `:options="options1"`, but React would do `options={options1}`.

Comment: @NathanStrutz More properly, the JSX equivalent.

Answer (score 12):

To add to [thanksd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44955735/4115031):

Those are [dynamic attributes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html). Basically it means that Vue.js will let you set the value of those attributes to variables, and when the value of those variables updates, the value of those attributes will update as well.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when using the colon in `HTML`because selecting the attribute in `CSS` and `JQuery`has a different meaning with a colon.  In `CSS` and `JQuery`, a colon signifies a `pseudo-selector`, which is different from `v-bind`;