# What does the colon represent inside a VueJS/Vuetify/HTML component tag

Tags: html, vue.js

I am using Vuetify, so this could be either a VueJS, Vuetify or even HTML question, but my component looks like this :

```html
<v-list-tile 
  v-for="item in menuItem.items" 
  :key="item.type" 
  :style="`background: ${item.colour}`" 
  :html="item.type">
</v-list-tile>
```

Take the `:key` for example, what does the colon (`:`) before the word `key` mean? And where can I find what values I can use ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean when an html attribute is prefixed with a colon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955696/what-does-it-mean-when-an-html-attribute-is-prefixed-with-a-colon)

Comment: @thanksd how did i not find this, i was looking for a while, thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`:key` is a shorthand for `v-bind:key`:

> The v- prefix serves as a visual cue for identifying Vue-specific
>   attributes in your templates. This is useful when you are using Vue.js
>   to apply dynamic behavior to some existing markup, but can feel
>   verbose for some frequently used directives. At the same time, the
>   need for the v- prefix becomes less important when you are building a
>   SPA where Vue.js manages every template. Therefore, Vue.js provides
>   special shorthands for two of the most often used directives, v-bind
>   and v-on

https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand

Comment: i did actually look on that page. Must have glanced over it. Makes sense, thanks