# Transition on :class with tailwind

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

So this is a fairly simple one I hope. I have a div in a vue file

`<div class="h-screen flex overflow-hidden" :class="darkMode">`

I have a script of

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      darkMode: 'light'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clickDarkMode () {
      if (this.darkMode === "dark") {
        this.darkMode = "light"
      } else {
        this.darkMode = "dark"
      }
    }
  },
```

When someone clicks a button to change from light to dark or vice versa, I want the dark / light mode to transition in so it isnt POW in your face. I understand in Tailwind Transitions but no matter where I put the utility classes, they just dont activate. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could also use pure CSS transitions (with a hidden trigger input checkbox) without any JavaScript at all fwiw.

Comment: (For those wondering, the `:class` attribute is used by VueJS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541835/what-does-the-colon-represent-inside-a-vuejs-vuetify-html-component-tag )

Comment: I do not want to use Pure CSS as that defeats the whole purpose of using a Utility CSS system like Tailwind.

Comment: Not necessarily - some CSS _systems_ like Bootstrap do play-nice with clean CSS. I'm not familiar with Tailwind to know if it lets you easily use your own stylesheets - but this is why I tend to stay away from premade systems: too many things break and trying to keep up with the update-treadmill is exhausting.

Comment: At the end of the day, what you are suggesting is NOT in line with my question. Also, adding Vue.JS to the question isnt valid because this has nothing to do with that. This has to do with javascript in general.

Comment: I never edited your question. Even so, **it is important to state you're using VueJS** because Vue controls the DOM and Vue uses `:class="darkMode"` and you're asking why _it's not working_. The fact you're using Vue is very relevant to your question. If you don't want to include Vue in your question then **please post a reproducible example** [as a StackOverflow HTML snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet) - otherwise we cannot help you.